# Relation between surface integral and lebesgue integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, surface-integrals

Let $f :\mathbb{R}^{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and $B_{R}$ be the $N$-dimensional ball. I consider
\begin{align*}\tag{1.1}\int_{\partial B_{R}}f(x)dS\end{align*}
as the surface integral of $f$ on the surface of $B_{R}$. However, I can also define
\begin{align*}
\chi_{\partial_{B_{R}}}:=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad&\text{ if }x\in\partial B_{R}\\
0 \quad&\text{ if }x\not\in\partial B_{R}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then, I consider
\begin{align*}\tag{1.2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}f(x)\chi_{\partial B_{R}}dx \end{align*}
So, my question is to consider whether (1.1) and (1.2) are the same integral or not. Specifically, I would like to know also whether
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}f(x)\chi_{\partial B_{R}}dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}f(x)\chi_{\partial B_{R}}dS$ can be considered the same integral or not in this case.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Your second integral is always $0$ since its integrand is $0$ except on a set of ($N$-dimensional Lebesgue) measure $0$. What you need is not the characteristic function but the uniform measure concentrated on the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

They are not. For the surface $\partial B_{R}$, it is of measure zero by taking the Lebesgue measure, so 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x)\chi_{\partial B_{R}}(x)dx=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: I see, thank you very much.
Actually, I am trying to see the limit of $\int_{\partial B_{R}}f(x)dS$ as $R\to\infty$ provided $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ and smooth. I am thinking to convert the surface integral into Lebesgue integral to apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence but this might not be a good idea